# How to combine HttpResponseRedirect & render_to_response?

Tags: python, django

When the user gets logged in, he is redirected to the "/welcome/" url by HttpResponseRedirect. But I also want to return the statement which is commented out below it as I also want to pass on the dictionary to the template. Help me with a method to combine these two statements or any other solution.

## Views.py

```
   def home(request):
        templatename="login.html"
        if request.method=="POST":
            u=request.POST.get("username")     
            p=request.POST.get("password")
            user=authenticate(username=u, password=p)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    print "This User is valid, active and authenticated"
                    login(request,user)
                    state = "You're successfully logged in!"
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("/welcome/")
                    #return render_to_response(templatename,{'state':state, 'user':user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

    
                else:
                    print "This User is valid but the account has been disabled"
                    state="This User is valid but the account has been disabled"
    
            else:
                print "The Username and Password entered were incorrect"
                state = "Your username and/or password were incorrect."
                #return render_to_response(templatename,{'state':state, 'user':user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    
        else:
            user=None
            state=None
    
        return render_to_response(templatename, {'state':state, 'user':user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use message framework for that .. `from django.contrib import messages`

*views.py*

```
messages.success(request, "You're successfully logged in!")
return HttpResponseRedirect("/welcome/")
```

Another option is just to use session for that.! but in session you will find the way to hide the message after displaying ...

```
#views.py
request.session['state'] = "You're successfully logged in!"
HttpResponseRedirect("/welcome/")
#html
{{ request.session.state }}
```

Comment: Where does this message show up? and don't we have to return the HttpResponseRedirect?

Comment: [displaying-messages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/messages/#displaying-messages)